# Force BIOS to boot into Boot Menu every time

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd, bios, windows-10

I have a dual boot system booting Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and Windows 10 Pro on an [ASRock X99 WS-E](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157538&cm_re=asrock_x99_ws-e-_-13-157-538-_-Product) motherboard (therefore ASUS BIOS) on 2 separate SSDs (one for each boot). I'm using each system in about equal amounts, and having to repeatedly press `f11` half the time to choose my Ubuntu install over Windows gets rather tedious; especially if I need to switch back and forth numerous times a day.

I'm looking to force my system to automatically open the Boot Menu when it boots so I can boot up my computer, go elsewhere, then choose a boot disk when I come back. I don't like having to watch it like a hawk on every boot-up.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain? I'm new to this site in the stack family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most BIOS do not have a setting for what you describe.

Configure GRUB / Windows boot options on your primary drive.  Either can boot to both drives and can have optional timeouts.

Comment: Can you describe *how*? That would make this answer feel a lot better